# Como puedo pasar varios items en otra actividad

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Tengo una lista llena de items , y quería pasar 3 de los items en una otra actividad, luego vuelvo en la lista para pasar 3 otros items mas ..así sucesivamente (los items elegidos deben aparecer en forma de lista ).

Este es mi código:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    MenuInflater inflate = getMenuInflater();
    if (v.getId() == R.id.listView) {

        inflate.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    }
}
public boolean onContextItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info= (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    GetContacts get = new GetContacts();
    String datas=get.doInBackground().toString();
    Log.d("RESULT",datas);
        int id = info.position;
    View view=info.targetView;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case  R.id.iva:
            TextView textView3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtCodigo);
            TextView textView4 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDescrip);
            TextView textView5 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtPrecio);

            String text3 = textView3.getText().toString();
            String text4 = textView4.getText().toString();
            String text5 = textView5.getText().toString();
            Intent intent3= new Intent(busqueda.this,Carrito.class);
            final Intent intent = intent3.putStringArrayListExtra("CODE", ArrayList);
            intent3.putExtra("CODE", text3);
            intent3.putExtra("PRODUC", text4);
            intent3.putExtra("PRECIO", text5);


            startActivity(intent3);
    }
return true;
```

y la Otra actividad que recibe... recibe solo una sola fila de item....quiero agregar en la otra actividad como lista todos los items seleccionados...
GRACIAS

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_carrito);
    productos = new ArrayList<>();
    texto=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    txtcod=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    txtpre=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);

    final Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extra = intent.getExtras();
    if (extra != null) {
        String dato = extra.getString("CODE");
        String Tok = extra.getString("PRODUC");
        String Token2 = extra.getString("PRECIO");

        texto.setText(dato);
        txtcod.setText(Tok);
        txtpre.setText(Token2);

    }
}
```

Comment: 3 items, te refieres a esto:  intent3.putExtra("CODE", text3);
            intent3.putExtra("PRODUC", text4);
            intent3.putExtra("PRECIO", text5); ???

Comment: si , son los campos que estan en una de las filas de la lista ... logre a pasar los items pero lo que quiero es pasar mas items de la lista a otro actividad ,  que almacenan los items en una Arraylist ....

Comment: Para pasar mas items, yo crearia una lista personalizada, agregando checkbox o algo similar para seleccionar los elementos que se desean, y manejar todo en el adapter. Asi lanzar la segunda actividad con un Arraylist que contenga todas las filas seleccionadas

Comment: Puedes pasar un ArrayList con todos los elementos que quieras, la forma de gestionarlo es con un objeto 'parcelable' o 'serializable'.

Answer (score 1):

Como opción es crear un objeto con los campos "CODE", "PRODUC" y "PRECIO", importante hacer notar que este objeto debe implementar la clase `Serializable` para que pueda ser enviada mediante un `bundle` entre `Activities`, por ejemplo:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Producto implements Serializable{

    private String code;
    private String produc;
    private String precio;


    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getProduc() {
        return produc;
    }

    public void setProduc(String produc) {
        this.produc = produc;
    }

    public String getPrecio() {
        return precio;
    }

    public void setPrecio(String precio) {
        this.precio = precio;
    }

}
```

Posteriormente, crear un `ArrayList` donde almacenes estos elementos con sus respectivos valores y de esta forma puedes enviar el `ArrayList` con la información entre `Activities`.

#### Enviar ArrayList entre Activities.

Pero definitivamente la forma ideal es enviar los datos entre Activities a travez del `bundle`.

Donde tu objeto debe implementar  la clase `Serializable`:

```
public class Dato implements Serializable {
```

Enviarias un ArrayList de objetos en el Intent mediante `.putExtra()`:

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SegundaActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("listaDatos", listaDatos);
                startActivity(intent);
```

Para recibir el ArrayList en la Activity destino, se realiza de esta forma:

```
ArrayList<listaDatos> listaDatos = (ArrayList<listaDatos> ) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("listaDatos");
```

Comment: muchas gracias @Jorgesys , lo que pasa , los resultados de (los 3 items ) lo saco desde los textview de la lista en un popup menu

Comment: entonces como obtendrías varios campos?

Comment: con un bucle for me parece no se bn , es que cada vez que capturo los items y los mando en la otra activity , debo capaz de voler en la lisata a eligir otro items mas ... etc etc...