# Pasar un ArrayList de tipo objeto a otra Actividad o Activity en Android

Tags: android, arraylist, objeto

Buenas noches, estoy intentando pasar un arraylist de tipo objeto de un activity a otro pero no me ha dado resultado. He intentado de esta forma sin exito.

Activity 1:

```
ArrayList<DatosReferencia> Lista = new ArrayList<>();

//Lo ejecuta un boton
   Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ReferenciasFavoritas.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable("Lista",  Lista);
            i.putExtras(bundle);// Tambien lo he intentado con i.putExtra("Lista",  Lista); Quitando el bundle
            startActivity(i);
```

Activity 2:

```
ArrayList<DatosReferencia> lista = (ArrayList<DatosReferencia> ) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Lista");
```

La clase DatosReferencia la tengo asi:

```
public class DatosReferencia implements Serializable // No posee subclases
```

La traza del error es esta:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.anaperez.myapplication, PID: 20802
              java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4646)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19403)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
               Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4646) 
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19403) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
               Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.example.anaperez.myapplication.DatosReferencia)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1316)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1264)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:653)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1226)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:618)
                  at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1692)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:636)
                  at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:7327)
                  at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2276)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1425)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3510)
                  at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:67)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3471)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:720)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3713)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3681)
                  at com.example.anaperez.myapplication.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:121)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4646) 
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19403) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
               Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: android.graphics.Bitmap
                  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1364)
                  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
                  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
                  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
                  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:979)
                  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:368)
                  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1074)
                  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1404)
                  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
                  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
                  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1311)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1264) 
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:653) 
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1226) 
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:618) 
                  at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1692) 
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:636) 
                  at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:7327) 
                  at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2276) 
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1425) 
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3510) 
                  at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54) 
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:67) 
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3471) 
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:720) 
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3713) 
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3681) 
                  at com.example.anaperez.myapplication.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:121) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4646) 
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19403) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Muchas gracias por sus sugerencias.

Comment: Una opción que tienes es pasar la lista a un Json y pasarlo a través del intent (con putExtra o putString). Una vez en la siguiente actividad, lo recoges como string y lo pasas de nuevo a lista.

Comment: Hola Ana P., Bienvenida, te aconsejo buscar en el sitio, puede ser que lo que buscas ya se encuentra en el sitio. Por ejemplo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/80727/como-puedo-pasar-varios-items-en-otra-actividad/80821#80821

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te recomiendo que implementes [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) en lugar de `Serializable` que es más rápido (El proceso de serialización crea muchos objetos por lo cual es más trabajo para el GC) y está pensado para estas ocasiones.

El código para ponerlo en el intent sería el siguiente:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ReferenciasFavoritas.class);
i.putParcelableArrayListExtra("Lista",  Lista);
startActivity(i);
```

Y para recuperarlo desde el intent:

```
ArrayList<DatosReferencia> lista = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("Lista");
```

Si necesitas ayuda para implementar `parcelable`, agrega el código de la clase `DatosReferencia`

Comment: "Parcelable en lugar de Serializable que es más rápido", solo que para meter los atributos de la clase, es mas lento...

Comment: @Jorgesys a que te referis con "meter atributos de la clase"? Tenes tipo de información mas detallada al respecto?